# What's the difference between sell and sale as nouns?

Tags: meaning

I have two different Merriam Webster thesaurus dictionaries, I looked for the word sell as a noun and I couldn't find it, then I looked for the word sale but I did not find the word sell as a synonym, since in the online Merriam Webster dictionary, one of its meanings is "the act of selling, I cannot understand why for native speakers, there is a meaning difference.

Comment: A **sell** is the talk the salesperson gives to prospective buyers. "It was a hard sell" does not mean it was difficult, but *intensely pressured*.

Comment: ***sell*** is rarely used as a noun. The only context I can think of is ***That was a hard sell*** = *It was difficult to close that sale***. But you *never* need to use it, so just don't. Snap! @WeatherVane!

Comment: @FumbleFingers ... but a slightly different take on what a "hard sell" is.

Comment: Well, [hard sell](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hard-sell) = *a method of selling in which the person selling tries very hard to persuade the customer to buy something*. Both are close enough for our purposes here.

Comment: You never say whether you found the noun "sell" in a dictionary. It is listed in M-W online as well as many other dictionaries.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I agree. I can't really think of any other use of sell as a noun. It only really exists in that particular expression. "a hard sell".   The OED lists other examples of sell as a noun, but they're all more or less obsolete or very rare today.  These are: Sell, an act of betraying/giving up to justice. Sell, a saddle. Sell, a contrivance/fiction.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan: OP says he *did* find "the act of selling" in M-W. I assume the problem is he couldn't find any examples of its actual *use* out in the wild. Unsurprisingly, given the comments above. It's a perfectly good question, and hopefully OP will be pleased to learn that his command of English won't suffer if he simply forgets about the noun usage. (It's always good to find you've got one thing less to learn! :)

Comment: @BillyKerr  - When I was young, people in the UK, might say 'what a sell!' about a deceptive act which they have suffered from, I think the nearest modern words might be 'swizz' or 'swindle'.

Comment: And then there is a [sell-out](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sell-out) - all the tickets have been sold.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Showing your age again! [Chambers Universal Learners Dictionary](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Chambers_Universal_Learners_Dictionary/AB1f965CUnwC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22what+a+sell%22&pg=PA661&printsec=frontcover) said the usage was *informal, **old*** back in 1980!

Comment: @FumbleFingers He (or she) says he found that definition for "sale", and a glance at M-W online confirms that "the act of selling" is part of the definition of ["sale"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sale), not ["sell"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sell).

Comment: @MarcInManhattan: Perhaps the OP can enlighten us, but I understand his text to mean he *did* find it in M-W. I linked to the separate definition for **hard sell**, but checking [their entry for **sell**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sell) I find ***an act of selling** or trying to sell a product or service*, just as described in the Q. Their definition for **sale** is slightly different: *an act of exchanging something for money.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers - OK I'll admit it was something I read in stuff like the Famous Five and William.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, the definitions are very close, but I think that that highlights why it's so important to mention that he actually found both: If we can confirm that, then we can focus on why he doesn't understand the differences between two definitions that are so similar. Otherwise we have to mess around with whether he missed the most relevant definition, whether he's looking at Cambridge vs. M-W, etc. It's very basic info and needs to be included, IMO.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan In the Collins dictionary it is defined as an act of selling as well, and here https://www.dictionary.com/e/sale-vs-sell/#:~:text=Sell%20or%20sale%3A%20when%20to,%2C%20or%20easy%2C%20use%20sell. they talk about the specific difference between sell and sale which I found confusing as English makes nouns out of evreything.

Comment: I think they could  perfectly be synonyms even though you do not use them that way.

Comment: @Quique Yes, that's the kind of information that should be included in the question.

Comment: @WeatherVane: "It was a hard sell" _can_ express that it was difficult, not necessarily pressured. Using the old saying, "trying to sell ice to an eskimo" is an example of a "hard sell" that is difficult (since they don't need more ice, as the saying goes) but not necessarily pressured (if you have plenty of other buyers).

Comment: @Flater that's a verb in the expression, not a noun.

Comment: @WeatherVane: I'm not talking about the literal word "sell" in "trying to sell ice to an eskimo". I'm saying that the act of trying to sell ice to an eskimo is a difficult thing to do, therefore it is a hard sell. The point I'm making is that "hard sell" _can_ mean something that is difficult, which you incorrectly claimed to not be the case. (Quote: _""It was a hard sell" does not mean it was difficult, but intensely pressured."_)

Comment: @Flater - I could say that when I bought a car, the salesman _gave me the hard sell_ by trying to load the deal with extras which I didn't want.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I did not claim that it _never_ means it was pressured. I countered the claim that it allegedly never means that it was a challenge. Both are possible interpretations.

Comment: There is another use of **sell** as a noun, albeit rather technical. In printed matter, the sell can be the sub-heading under an article's main title. Usually the title is a few words in a big typeface **Joe wins race**,the sell would be next in an intermediate size typeface *Joe Soap came first the 23rd running of the Someshire Marathon last Saturday*  followed by the rest of the article reporting the race in detail. It serves as a synopsis of the story to get the reader interested.

Answer (score 3):

As nouns, ***sale*** and ***sell*** aren't really synonymous. True synonyms are extremely rare in English (if indeed they exist at all! :), so it's not really a useful word or concept anyway.

There are just a handful of "frozen" idiomatic usages involving ***sell*** as a noun...

> [**hard sell**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hard-sell)
> *a method of selling in which the person selling tries very hard to persuade the customer to buy something.*

> [**sell-out**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sell-out)
> *a situation where the entire supply of something has been sold*
> OR
> *an act of betrayal*

> **sell-off** (Stock Market)
> *the rapid / high-volume selling of bonds, shares, or commodities, usually causing a fall in price*

Note that they all differ from the standard noun ***sale*** in that they specifically emphasize the ***act*** of selling, rather than the broader range covered by ***sale*** (most of which focus on *[financial] **transaction*** rather than *[seller's] **action***).

Answer (score 0):

“Selling” is an activity that may encompass many discrete acts; it is a noun made from a verb, “sell.”

> His new job is selling cars.

It does not refer to any specific transactions.

“Sale” is a noun with several meanings. But the most common is “an act of selling.” When that meaning is intended, it usually refers to one or more transactions that are specific in some context.

> The Smiths finally closed on the sale of their house.

> Sales of refrigerators are correlated with construction of new housing.

In general, verbs in English do not act as nouns although there are plenty of exceptions (*e.g.* “contract” although that word is pronounced differently in American English when used as a verb or a noun). As the comments point out, there are certain idioms where “sell” is used as a noun, but usually “sell” is used only as a verb.

Verbs in English can be turned into nouns by adding the suffix “ing” to the root verb. So, “selling” can be used as a noun. When there is a noun with a meaning very close to a verb + “ing,” the two forms are often used in slightly different ways. As I explained above, “selling” can be used as a noun, and “sale” is a noun, but they usually have slightly different connotations.

**EDIT**: I should add that my answer is limited to American English. I do not know British or Indian English, and my answer may not apply to one or the other or even both.